# Time Series Prediction Model for Home Prices

Tags: time-series, self-study, forecasting, arima, missing-data

I am building a time series model to predict the zillow home prices for march 2019.I have data for each zip code from the year 1993 - 2018 and i have prices for every month.I was trying to use ARIIMA Model since there is no seasonality in the data.But the problem is there are a lot of missing values for the years 1993-2006,but there are no missing values from 2006.So should i consider only the data from 2006-2018 and use ARIIMA to predict prices for march 2019? If i do this I would be wasting the data which i have from 1993-2006.I guess there should be an alternate way.Please give me suggestions

I had a suggestion to use state space implementation to deal with the missing values:

How can use this?
Can i include that as a parameter in ARIIMA?

Comment: Home prices are VERY seasonal, not sure why you don't see in your data

Comment: I am using ARIIMA and including the seasonality factor.But my main problem is dealing with the missing data.For example for zip code 10013 i have the data from jan 2003 - Dec 2017.How can i impute the missing values for Jan 1993- Jan 2003?

Comment: Look for state-space implementation of your time series model, they deal with missing data naturally